# itemsselected.count always returns 0 - ms access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a listbox where i want to get the values per column but the code below always returns itemsselected.count as 0

```
Dim item As Variant

    If Me.Lst_ProcVeri_CardInfo.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each item In Me.Lst_ProcVeri_CardInfo.ItemsSelected
            a = Me.Lst_ProcVeri_CardInfo.Column(1, item)
            b = Me.Lst_ProcVeri_CardInfo.Column(2, item)
        Next item
    End If
```

can anyone give advice on this?

Answer (score 2):

Always remember to set `multi select` function to `EXTENDED`!

Comment: THANK YOU. 2 years on and this just saved me. MulitiSelect = None, no selected items for you. What!?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ListIndex` when not using `EXTENDED` to return the selected value's index.